# Is an empty slice the same as a null pointer?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is the following empty slice the same as a null pointer?

```
slice = Slice(UInt8).empty
slice.size # => 0
```

The [source code](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/80a975cf0a98a4ce8464d0069145131667becd70/src/slice.cr#L136) of `#empty` implies a null pointer (address 0 and size 0):

```
  def self.empty
    new(Pointer(T).null, 0)
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"?

Comment: @RX14 I don't know. (I'm sorry.) Maybe I should rephrase the question: "How is `Slice(T).new(Pointer(T).null, 0)` used/useful?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of the [Null-Object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) pattern:

The empty slice can be used in all places that take a reqular slice, without requiring explicit Nil-Checks.

A similar example would be returning an empty string on nil or having a GuestUser that has the same properties as a regular User.